# Security Vulnerability with Apache using default password

Tags: apache, security, hex

One of the servers in our estate has been reported to use "Apache" default userid and password. The message we have from security monitoring tool "envision" is as follows

```
SEND String[GET /manager/html HTTP/1.0\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a] THEN CHECK Contains/^HTTP\/1\.[01] 401/ WITH Length[12] BEFORE Contains[\x0d\x0aWWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Tomcat Manager Application"] BEFORE Contains[\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a] 
THEN RECONNECT THEN SEND String[GET /manager/html HTTP/1.0\x0d\x0aAuthorization: Basic YWRtaW46\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a] THEN CHECK Contains/^HTTP\/1\.[01] [23][0-9]{2}/ WITH Length[12]
```

Can someone help in understanding what the above statement checks for?
How to convert these `[\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a]` into human readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Tomcat is an open source Servlet Container.

Using the manager interface of Apache Tomcat you could deploy a new Web Application in the server. This is protected with an username and password but it seems that in this case the administrator didn't implement strong credentials.

An attacker could guess ("bruteforcing attack") the username and password, deploy a malicious app such as a Web Shell that allows him/her to execute commands and take over the affected server.

The "\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a" part, can be humanly readable if you replace the "\x" for a "%" and then decode it to URL format where each two characters are a representation in HEX of the ASCII readable character. In this case the two characters "%0d%0a" are jump lines.

The part that says:

> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46

Is a weak authorization method, where the credentials travel trough a header and they are encoded in Base 64. In this case decoding the "YWRtaW46" string to B64 would mean "admin:".

By this we could translate the warning that you showed in "I find a weak administration panel in Apache Tomcat in the path /manager/html using the username admin and no password"

Comment: thanks lgarr. But I'm sure password is present i.e. m4n4ger (which is the default).

Comment: I was just helping you understand what that warning says. And according to the encoded B64 there's no password, at least in that encoded string. The default tomcat password could be "tomcat" and i said could because actually there isn't, you have to uncomment the  tomcat-users XML for that to be applied.